# how can I push data in a matrix with angular 7

Tags: arrays, angular

this is the array of objects I have :

```
 [
  {
   indicatorDatasource: "trackingError", 
   un_an: 0,
   trois_ans: 0,
   cinq_ans: 0
  },
  {
   indicatorDatasource: "annualisedFundPerformance",
   un_an: 19.749642029434945,
   trois_ans: 0.08025487443092949,
   cinq_ans: -3.819180707679881
  },
  {
   indicatorDatasource: "volatility",
   un_an: 27.581656736670507,
   trois_ans: 17.12568099017286, 
   cinq_ans: 13.426711413441112
  }]
```

**I want to transform it like that :**

```
[
      [ 'trackingError', 'annualisedFundPerformance', 'volatility' ],
      [ '0', '19.749642029434945', '27.581656736670507'],
      [ '0', '3.819180707679881', '13.426711413441112' ]
 ]
```

So I create a variable `tableOptions : String[][]` then I added elements from `dataSourceObject` like that :

```
this.datasourceObject.forEach(element => {
  this.tableOptions[].push(element["indicatorDatasource"])
});
this.datasourceObject.forEach(element => {
  this.tableOptions[].push[(element["un_an"].toString())]
});
this.datasourceObject.forEach(element => {
  this.tableOptions[].push[(element["trois_ans"].toString())]
});
this.datasourceObject.forEach(element => {
  this.tableOptions[].push[(element["cinq_ans"].toString())]
});
```

But it gives me an error `Error : An element access expression should take an argument`.
Can anyone help me how to transform it in the format I want ?

Comment: you forget: 1.-when declare tableOptions declare as empty array `tableOptions:any[]=[]`, 2.- use `this.tableOptions[0].push(..), this.tableOptions[1].push(...)`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj=[{ indicatorDatasource: "trackingError",  un_an: 0,  trois_ans: 0, cinq_ans: 0},{indicatorDatasource: "annualisedFundPerformance", un_an: 19.749642029434945, trois_ans: 0.08025487443092949, cinq_ans: -3.819180707679881},{indicatorDatasource: "volatility", un_an: 27.581656736670507, trois_ans: 17.12568099017286, cinq_ans: 13.426711413441112}]

var result=[];
Object.keys(obj[0] ? obj[0] : []).forEach(key=>{
    var temp=[];
    obj.forEach(cell=>{temp.push(cell[key].toString())});
    result.push(temp);
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.

```
  let finalArray = [];
  for (let [key] of Object.entries(this.datasourceObject[0])) {
    let result = a.map(order => 
      order[key]);
      finalArray.push(result);
}
console.log(finalArray);
```